# why samsung s5 display is not what i expected

Tags: responsive-design, media-queries

samsung s5 display:1080 x 1920 pixels but in my `media query` at this screen size target

`@media handheld, screen and (max-width: 970px) {}`

the image show the problem:

[image]

by the way I used this `meta tag` inside `head tag`

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "px" unit in CSS doesn't actually mean a physical pixel on the screen.  It's a device-independent unit that refers to the (approximate) size of a pixel on a traditional PC monitor, and browsers are expected to scale it appropriately when rendering to a high-DPI device like a printer or a modern "retina" display.  So although your phone's screen is 1080 *physical* pixels wide, it's far fewer *CSS* pixels wide.

The exact definition of the "px" unit has varied across CSS versions, but all they all define it with approximately the same physical size.  [CSS3 says](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths) "1px is equal to 1/96th of 1in" — the size that a physical pixel would be on a 96dpi monitor.

Wikipedia says that the Galaxy S5's screen is 2.85 inches wide.  With 96 CSS pixels per inch, that'd make it about 274px wide from a CSS standpoint.